# change background color of drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the back ground color for drop down menu....
i tried chnage color for sub div but its not working...
how to fix it....
providing my code below....

http://jsfiddle.net/3VBQ6/4/

```
#nav li:hover ul.sub li {
    display:block;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
    font-weight:normal;
}
#nav li:hover ul.sub li a {
    display:block;
    font-size:11px;
    height:18px;
    line-height:18px;
    text-indent:5px;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid #bbd37e;
}
#nav li ul.sub li a.fly {
    background:#bbd37e url(arrow.gif) 80px 6px no-repeat;
}
#nav li:hover ul.sub li a:hover {
    background:#e3e3e3;
    color:#fff;
    border-color:#fff;
}
#nav li:hover ul.sub li a.fly:hover {
    background:#6a812c url(arrow_over.gif) 80px 6px no-repeat;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: not quite sure what you want to do

Comment: when you hover over the links u would see a drop down menu how to change the back ground color for it...

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..

```
#nav li:hover ul.sub {
  background: #00E248;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/3VBQ6/5/)